# How to redirect domain folder directly to domain using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have problem with my domain folder on cPanel.
Domain is working fine, but when I open folder path for that domain, it is not redirecting me directly to domain, and that is also a problem with Google indexing also. So here is example:

> Main domain: www.domain1.com
>
> Second domain: www.domain2.com
>
> Folder for second domain: www.domain1.com/domain2

So the problem is when I open path www.domain1.com/domain2 it is not redirecting me to www.domain2.com. Directly www.domain2.com works fine.

I have tried with cPanel redirection, but it is not working, so I think that .htaccess is solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain1.com/domain2/ [R=301,L]
```